# How to correctly implement Modals from semantic-ui-react library on button clicks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to implement [this](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal#modal-example-modal) basic modal from the semantic-ui-react library and want this modal to show up whenever a button is clicked. Below is the code:

```
const ModalModalExample = () => (
  <Modal trigger={<Button>Show Modal</Button>}>
    <Modal.Header>Select a Photo</Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Content image>
    <Image wrapped size='medium' src='/assets/images/avatar/large/rachel.png' />
      <Modal.Description>
        <Header>Default Profile Image</Header>
        <p>We've found the following gravatar image associated with 
        your e-mail address.</p>
        <p>Is it okay to use this photo?</p>
      </Modal.Description>
      </Modal.Content>
  </Modal>
)
```

I'm importing this component in another jsx file where I want to use it but only the button shows up and there's no functionality to it:

```
<span><ModalModalExample/></span>
```

Comment: This example looks correct, can you make a codepen that shows issue?

Comment: @alexander I switched to react-modal library from semantic react, applied some custom css and it worked.